# Set InfoPath 2010 form to grade mulitiple choice

Tags: list, infopath

I have set up an InfoPath 2010 form with drop-down list answers that I changed to radio buttons. When a selection is made and submitted, the answer(ID) is sent to a SharePoint 2010 list.

[image]

[image]

My question is how would I create a rule or formula to grade each question? For example if C is the correct answer, how would I create a way for question 1 to earn 1pt for the correct answer and then total the number of points (correct answers) at the end of the form for the overall grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another field in the list for the grade. In the InfoPath form, set the value of that field to "1" if answered correctly. Then create a view or a DVWP that aggregates the correct answers. If you want to show the total points in the IP form, you need to add a secondary data source to the same list, pull all the values for the current user and total them. Refresh the secondary data source after each question.

Comment: thanks teylyn. Do you know of a step by step procedure that could help me out?